# visual Div reposition onclick css js

Tags: javascript, css, html

Trying to visually reposition two divs with onclick whenever each is clicked.
Is it possible to swap the complete CSS of each div onclick to achieve this effect?

Would this be considered the best practice or is there a 
better way to rearrange div containers.

Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/Gx9B9/1/

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
<title>Lines</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="box_a">
<div id="box_b">
</div>
<div id="box_g">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
/* Wrap all Divs */

#box_a {
}

/* Background Div */
#box_b {
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
background: black;
}

/* Foreground Div */

#box_g {
position: absolute;
top: 14.05%;
right: 20%;
bottom: 20%;
left: 20%;
background: white;
z-index: 99;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Base your css on class not on div id, after you just need to change the  class of the div when you click on it.

```
    function changeClass()
    {
      if (document.getElementById("box_b").className == 'first_css')
         document.getElementById("box_b").className = 'second_css';
      else
         document.getElementById("box_b").className = 'first_css';
    }
```

I have update it on :
http://jsfiddle.net/Gx9B9/2/

Comment: Quick follow up: What I am trying to do is switch the position of the boxes (and their content). Like: white box on black box -> click white box -> the two switch position (but keep all their original content). This example seems to switch boxes but doesn't keep the design of a box on top of a box.

Comment: I have update, http://jsfiddle.net/Gx9B9/13/, but you can do what you want to do, just by apply a specific css class to your div and change the css class when you click on the box